# Command "pecl install mongodb" throw me : No releases available for package "pecl.php.net/mongodb"

Tags: php, mongodb, ubuntu-20.04, pecl

I have to install mongodb extension into my ubuntu server (20.04.5).

I try this command `pecl install mongodb` but it throws me this error `No releases available for package "pecl.php.net/mongodb"`.

So how can I install it because all my searches tell me to use this command...

Comment: Have you tried `sudo pecl install mongodb`?

Comment: And `pecl update-channels` then `pecl install mongodb`